# How to connect to containers on docker Overlay network from an external machine

Tags: docker, overlay, external, connectivity, swarm

Is there any known solution for enabling an external machine to connect to the containers on a docker swarm overlay network?

Comment: Why doesn't normal port mapping work? I suspect you might benefit from looking at how "services" work on Docker Swarm mode. It is designed to expose containers on multiple host servers, effectively implementing a load balanced solution between outside world across the containers running upon the overlay network

Answer (score 0):

The question **is** legitimate, see example below, however I do not know of a simple solution for it, I'll propose offhand a possible solution and would test later and update.

> Suppose you have a docker overlay network of many Kafkas running on a
>   couple of nodes (container hosts). All Kafka brokers communicate with
>   each other beautifully.
>
> When a Kafka **client** needs to access a Kafka **broker** it connects
>   to it (say somehow, supposedly even through Swarm's service external
>   port), but then that broken **may** reply that that data is in another
>   broker with and here is that other broker's IP (on the overlay
>   network)... meaning **Kafka client must be able to access to all Kafka
>   brokers** (overlay network).

You can do this easily if **everything** is **containerized**, but what if not?

You can do this with SDN, or an offhand solution:
*A container with two networks serving as a router with one "leg" on the overlay network and the other l2bridged to where that other VM or host is and route through it, you'd have to Swarm "constrain" it to run where the network from which you want overlay network access is available.* that should work!

If someone has another clean/clear solution I'm very interested too